# C++ IDE's with no support for dark themes

Tags: c++, ide

There is another C++ IDE besides Visual Studio that supports well dark themes?

I have to work also on linux and windows right now, so I can't afford to work on VS. The problem is that all the ide's that I have tried don't support very well dark themes. Sure you can change the editor colors, but the rest of the ide stays with the default color, which is really annoying (QtCreator, Code::Blocks).

[image]

Is there any alternative out there?

Comment: VS 2013 is OK, Codelite too.

Comment: Turn the monitor brightness down, they are right in front of you.  Have another look.

Comment: Note also that some part of some IDE use the system color, so you may change those part changing your OS (window) theme.

Comment: Yes, that I know, but in Windows I dont like that idea very much

Answer (score 2):

Here you have IDE from Jetbrains -> CLion:

https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Codelite](http://codelite.org/):

[Codelite gallery](http://codelite.org/gallery.php):

[image: zmrom-like-theme]

Comment: the only problem is that the autocomplete is not good

Comment: @lhahn: There is several option which may be useful as enabling clang completion.